# Exception during maven tomcat project,exception is cannot be cast to javax.servlet.Filter

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven, tomcat, servlet-filters

I am new to maven tomcat project. For compiling and running I have referred below link and followed the step by step process as given in the link.
http://bigleap.co.in/corp/2013/06/running-maven-project-within-eclipse-on-tomcat/
still I am facing issue.
This issue is occurred after maven tomcat run.As i followed the link first clean package step gets successfully build.Please let me know if there any missing package or any jar file.
I got the following exception

```
    Running war on http://localhost:8080/cci_gh_go
Oct 05, 2015 5:50:39 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
SEVERE: Exception starting filter shiroFilter
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy cannot be cast to javax.servlet.Filter
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:275)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4001)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4651)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:445)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Embedded.start(Embedded.java:825)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.AbstractRunMojo.startContainer(AbstractRunMojo.java:558)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.AbstractRunMojo.execute(AbstractRunMojo.java:255)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)

SEVERE: The web application [/cci_gh_go] appears to have started a thread named [Abandoned connection cleanup thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:run (default-cli) on project cci_gh_go: Could not start Tomcat: Protocol handler initialization failed: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind <null>:8080 -> [Help 1]
```

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Can you add the `pom.xml` that has been generated to your question ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Filter ClassCastException when running project on Tomcat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25099572/spring-filter-classcastexception-when-running-project-on-tomcat)

Comment: See also : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7708288/severe-exception-springsecurityfilterchain-classcastexception-delegatingf